# django template how to deal with models with a fk in the template

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

i need to display some data from the DB.
I need to display the OrderItem and all related OrderProperties (with a FK)
In the view i do something like:

```
orderitems = OrderItem.objects.all().filter(order=order)
properties = []
for item in orderitems:
    a = OrderItemDetail.objects.all().filter(orderitem=item)
    b = []
    for x in a:
        c = [x.detail.property.name, x.detail.value, x.detail.price, x.detail.detail_price_unit]
    b.append(c)
 properties.append(b)
```

At the end I have a list of properties that i need then in the template I use them:

```
 # orderitems loop - displaying item detail
 # displaying the properties
 {% for prop in properties %}
     {% for x in prop %}
          <big><b>{{x.0}}</b>: {{x.1}} (+{{x.2}}
          {% if x.3 == "m" %}
          &euro;/MQ
          {% endif %}
          {% if x.3 == "p" %}
          %
          {% else %}
          &euro;
          {% endif %}
          )</big><br />
      {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

That should produce an output like: `color: red (+0,0 € )`
All works fine but when there are 2 or more orderitems i get each property printed in each record (I would like to display only the properties related to the current item)

It wold be quite easy if I could perform the query in the loop (retrieving only the properties that i need to display in that loop cycle). Yeah, I could create the html element in python, but since I'm using a template engine it seems pretty idiot.

Do you know any way to do that?

PS. i know variable names are meaningless but I need something short while testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need this.

In view:

```
orderitems = OrderItem.objects.all().filter(order=order)
```

It template:

```
{% for order in orderitems %}
   {% for detail in order.orderitemdetail_set.all %}
      {{ detail.property.name }}... etc
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you may be looking for the [related_name functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects).

Using that, you wouldn't need all the crap in your view, and your template would look something like this:

```
{% for item in order.orderitem_set.all %}
    <!-- Print some stuff about the item -->

    {% for item_detail in item.orderitemdetail_set.all %}
        <!-- Do stuff with your item details -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ook, now we have race condition issue =)

Comment: Hah, sorry about that. I already had it all typed out in my editor when I saw your answer come in :-)

Comment: Thank you too, especially for the link to the doc!
+1

Comment: @Evan Brumley No problem, just joking =)